# How to apply LSTM with CNN

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

My input is of shape (1, 12000, 250, 150, 3) with labels as (1, 12000, 2) for the CNN. In other words, I am training a CNN on 250x150x3 images with 2 classes; [1,0] or [0,1].

This is ultimately to create a bot to play flappy bird. I have been told that adding LSTMs to classify a few frame concurrently is the way to go. So far I got to 0.984 val_acc with the following purely CNN architecture.

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(250,150,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(32, 32, 19), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

The accuracy:

```
Epoch 15/100
12800/12800 [==============================] - 89s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0390 - acc: 0.9889 - val_loss: 0.1422 - val_acc: 0.9717
Epoch 16/100
12800/12800 [==============================] - 89s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0395 - acc: 0.9883 - val_loss: 0.0917 - val_acc: 0.9821ss: - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.0399 - acc:
Epoch 17/100
12800/12800 [==============================] - 89s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0357 - acc: 0.9902 - val_loss: 0.1383 - val_acc: 0.9816
Epoch 18/100
12800/12800 [==============================] - 89s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0452 - acc: 0.9871 - val_loss: 0.1153 - val_acc: 0.9750
Epoch 19/100
12800/12800 [==============================] - 90s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0417 - acc: 0.9892 - val_loss: 0.1641 - val_acc: 0.9668
Epoch 20/100
12800/12800 [==============================] - 90s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0339 - acc: 0.9904 - val_loss: 0.0927 - val_acc: 0.9840
```

I have tried add a LSTM layer but I'm not sure what is going wrong:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-59e402ac3b8a> in <module>
     26 model.add(Dropout(0.5))
     27 
---> 28 model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(32, 19), return_sequences=True))
     29 
     30 model.add(Dense(2))

E:\Applications\Anaconda3\envs\pygpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    179                 self.inputs = network.get_source_inputs(self.outputs[0])
    180         elif self.outputs:
--> 181             output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    182             if isinstance(output_tensor, list):
    183                 raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '

E:\Applications\Anaconda3\envs\pygpu\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    530 
    531         if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 532             return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    533 
    534         # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

E:\Applications\Anaconda3\envs\pygpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    412                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
    413                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
--> 414                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    415 
    416                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.

E:\Applications\Anaconda3\envs\pygpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    309                                      self.name + ': expected ndim=' +
    310                                      str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
--> 311                                      str(K.ndim(x)))
    312             if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    313                 ndim = K.ndim(x)

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Keras docs says the arguments for LSTM are (units, input shape) and so on. I also read somewhere that TimeDistributed() is no longer needed so I didnt include it. Did I make a mistake in calculating the input shape for LSTM or am I missing something else completely?

---

Edit 1: I have removed flatten() layer and moved LSTM layer to right after conv layers, before fc layers. I have also added a reshape() so as to reshape the 4 dim output of the 4th conv layer to 3 dim which can then be input to the LSTM layer.

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(250,150,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
output_1 = model.output_shape

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
output_2 = model.output_shape

model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
output_3 = model.output_shape

model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
output_4 = model.output_shape

model.add(Reshape((15, 9)))
output_5 = model.output_shape
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(15, 9, 256), return_sequences=True))
```

These are the shapes of every output:

```
Conv_1: (None, 125, 75, 32)
Conv_2: (None, 62, 37, 64)
Conv_3: (None, 31, 18, 128)
Conv_4: (None, 15, 9, 256)
```

The following occurs when I tried to reshape the conv_4 so as to get a 3 dim input into LSTM:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-7f5240e41ae4> in <module>
     22 output_4 = model.output_shape
     23 
---> 24 model.add(Reshape((15, 9)))
     25 output_5 = model.output_shape
     26 model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(15, 9, 256), return_sequences=True))

E:\Applications\Anaconda3\envs\pygpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    179                 self.inputs = network.get_source_inputs(self.outputs[0])
    180         elif self.outputs:
--> 181             output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    182             if isinstance(output_tensor, list):
    183                 raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '

E:\Applications\Anaconda3\envs\pygpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    472             if all([s is not None
    473                     for s in to_list(input_shape)]):
--> 474                 output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
    475             else:
    476                 if isinstance(input_shape, list):

E:\Applications\Anaconda3\envs\pygpu\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py in compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
    396             # input shape known? then we can compute the output shape
    397             return (input_shape[0],) + self._fix_unknown_dimension(
--> 398                 input_shape[1:], self.target_shape)
    399 
    400     def call(self, inputs):

E:\Applications\Anaconda3\envs\pygpu\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py in _fix_unknown_dimension(self, input_shape, output_shape)
    384             output_shape[unknown] = original // known
    385         elif original != known:
--> 386             raise ValueError(msg)
    387 
    388         return tuple(output_shape)

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, i do not see lstm in your model, its just 4 convo to 3 full connected right?
Why do you have 2 Conv2D right after one another?

LSTM over frames i would do instead of  first full connected right after flatten.

I dont know in Keras, but input in any RNN cell is 3D array, like : 
(batch size, max sequence, items) or  (max_sequence, bach_size, items) , the second format is sort of weird.

The error you got is : 
`expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`

so i guess you enter 2D array instead of 3D

You sould modify your flatten to create valide 3D input.
This can you do for example by having 5d input but 2d convo like: 
bach size = 100, frames = 3, channels = 3, items = 28,28 (height, width), flatten to
(100, 3, -1) where -1 stands for rest.

I need to try similar stuff myself but i m doing in pytorch...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I commented out the LSTM layer above the last FC layer in the first block of code so as to show the working code first. The 2 conv layers of kernel size 3x3 one after another is to simulate a 5x5 kernel. I will try changing the input shape and the Flatten layer and see if it works, thanks again!

Comment: you welcome. Don't you know the trick is used when memory is not enoph to do 5x5 so you can just do one 5x5 :D

Comment: I was under the impression that 2 3x3 is faster than a 5x5 though I didn't know that more memory will be used. By the way, trying to implement LSTM now and ran into a problem. For ConvLSTM2D layer, input has to be (samples, timestep, rows, cols, channels) where timestep is number to frames per second. For example, if I want my bot to decide when to jump by looking at 5 consecutive frames, timestep should be an array of 5 consecutive images? So it will be say (10000, 5, 250, 150, 3) where the 5 is really [img, img, img, img, img]? Thanks for helping out, I'm learning lots !

Comment: yes thats the format For normal convo layer before that that should be make no difference  it runs parallel and have output with one more dimension. Also i guess ConvLSTM2D  has already lstm over maps so decide how do you want to do recurency over cnn or over full connected...

Comment: Hi there, if my input is (10000, 5, 250, 150, 3), what shape will my labels be? (10000, 2) where 2 is [0,1] or [1,0] as its one hot encoded? What happens if the 5 images have different classes? What will be the labels

Comment: labels depends from do you do seq to seq or seq to one , first variant you will have *timestep labels, second will have one , so : (10000,5, 2) for first, (10000, 2) for second. Depending what lstm output you use, for example in pytorch there is 2 outputs - for all timesteps (first variant) or just last timestep ( second)

Comment: or if you use batches for example of size 50 it will be (50, 200, 5,2) or (50, 200,2)

Comment: you r welcome. If you might, link me dataset you r using, i d like to try same stuff on pytorch

Comment: I have been trying to get the lstm to work but it has been throwing me a memory error. Anyways, according to this tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/training-self-driving-car-neural-network-python-plays-gta-v/ (which i closely followed), the bot can be trained purely on single frame inputs and perform on single frame inputs instead of stacked consecutive frames. I have tried training with the same number of images, the same model architecture(although im using keras and he is using tflearn) and I have now achieved 0.94 val_acc. When testing the model, again it does not perform as expected

Comment: If you don't mind, tinker with the data and see if you get similar results to mine or his. Maybe the architecture generalizes better for driving in gta than playing flappy bird? Or perhaps I've been doing something terribly wrong. Thanks for being responsive!

Comment: or cource that will consume lagre amount of memory, you could shrink images for initial training. Ok i ll do that task in next days

Answer (score 0):

If I had scrolled down a little more, I would have found ConvLSTM2D in the docs and this should solve my problem. Will try it now